# angularjs bind on mouseenter in directive not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I can't get the directiv i angular to bind on mouseenter, i have tried in a simple example, what is wrong here?

```
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <title>My AngularJS test</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
    <div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtr">
        <div testDir>test here</div>

        <!-- just testing to see if the app is working -->
        {{test}}


        <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

            app.directive("testDir", function(){

                return {

                    link: function(scope, element, attrs){

                        element.bind("mouseenter", function(){
                            console.log("enter")
                        })
                    }

                }


            })

            app.controller("testCtr", function($scope) {
                $scope.test = 500;
            })
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

IT is probably a stupid mistake, but i can't see it.

Comment: you omitted several semicolons? `console.log("enter");` being one. What does the log say?

Comment: @JeroenIngelbrecht - Semi-colons in JavaScript are not explicitly required; [ASI takes care of that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons).

Comment: ah, thanks so any warnings about that can be ignored then, unless you want to keep it clean and according to standards? (actually a genuine question without any sarcasm)

Comment: @JeroenIngelbrecht - Technically yes, but people get very opinionated about it. Check out this article: [**The Dangers of JavaScript’s Automatic Semicolon Insertion**](http://cjihrig.com/blog/the-dangers-of-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attribute should be snake cased:

```
<div test-dir>test here</div>
<!--     ^^               -->
```

Here's a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/bobVjZHSJ313ZLoXyKfB?p=preview

Comment: @JeroenIngelbrecht - How not? Did you check the console after mousing over the element?

Comment: @JeroenIngelbrecht - If there's some issue in your browser with Plunkr, check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBdYM/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

*Joseph Silber said everything right ,code is working,see your console!
here is more info about it*

**Directives have camel cased names such as 'ngBind'. The directive can be invoked by translating the camel case name into snake case with these special characters :, -, or _. Optionally the directive can be prefixed with x-, or data- to make it HTML validator compliant. Here is a list of some of the possible directive names: ng:bind, ng-bind, ng_bind, x-ng-bind and data-ng-bind.**

Answer (score 1):

HTML is case-insensitive. In order to normalize it we need to use dash-delimited attributes.